# Javascript Await reserved keyword error inside if statement

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

I am writing a small JS script where a user enters his IBAN and after entering the first 12 characters I am requesting the bank name and BIC from a different URL. As I have to wait for this request to finish, I made my function asynchronous and added an 'await' to the request. However, my script is no longer compiling with the following Error: 'Parsing error: await is a reserved word' pointing to my newly added 'await'. As this 'await' is inside several if conditions, i figured this might be the problem. However, it needs to be inside these if conditions. So does anyone has an idea what I am doing wrong and how to get the await inside the if condition?

This is my code:

```
function requestBICandBankname(country, bban) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    const url = URL + country.toUpperCase() + '/' + bban;

    xhr.open('GET', url, true);
    xhr.onload = function () {
      if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 300) {
        return resolve(xhr.response);
      }
      return reject({
        status: this.status,
        statusText: xhr.statusText
      });

    };
    xhr.onerror = function () {
      return reject({
        status: this.status,
        statusText: xhr.statusText
      });
    };
    xhr.send();

  });
}

async function initLookup() {
  const ibanData = document.getElementById('iban-details');
  let country = '';
  let bban;

  if (ibanData !== null) {
    ibanData.oninput = function (event) {
      const iban = ibanData.value;

      if (iban.length === 12) {
        country = iban.substr(0, 2);
        bban = iban.substr(4, 12);
        try {
          const bankdata = await requestBICandBankname(country, bban);
          console.log('bankdata', bankdata);
        } catch (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
      }
    };
  }

};

export {
  initLookup
};
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4q82fyr6/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only `await` inside a function that is declared as `async`.

The `ibanData.oninput` function is not declared that way.

Comment: oh i see! I only always looked at the parent function! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the event as a promise but should listen to an error as well (if that exists) or it'll never continue if it fails in some way:

```
const inputAsPromise = (ibanData) =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    ibanData.oninput = resolve;
    //@todo: onerror should be reject
  });
async function initLookup() {
  const ibanData = document.getElementById('iban-details');
  let country = '';
  let bban;

  if (ibanData !== null) {
    await inputAsPromise(ibanData);
    const iban = ibanData.value;

    if (iban.length === 12) {
      country = iban.substr(0, 2);
      bban = iban.substr(4, 12);
      try {
        const bankdata = await requestBICandBankname(
          country,
          bban,
        );
        console.log('bankdata', bankdata);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The problem with the code above is that `oninput` probably fires multiple times but you can only resolve the promise once. If that is the case then you can resolve it only if certain conditions are met:

```
const inputAsPromise = (ibanData) =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    ibanData.oninput = (e)=>ibanData.value.length === 12?resolve():'';
    //@todo: onerror should be reject
  });
```

That was just an example, you have to see what would work in your case.